# Java Derby Database delete all rows from a table

Tags: java, sql, derby

I need to delete all the rows in an Apache Derby database in Java.
If I execute `statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE CONDITION=")` it works, but if I try `statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM TABLENAME")` it does not delete all the rows. I tried `TRUNCATE` and it does not work either.

Any ideas.

Comment: Are you getting an error when "it does not work"?

Comment: No error. Just that I then dump the content in a file and it does not perform the delete.

Comment: Are you closing your `Statement` properly (thus triggering a `COMMIT`)? Sharing some more code could help.

Comment: `statement.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE TABLENAME")` should work -- and should be much faster than a `DELETE` because it's DDL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dummy condition to delete all the records :

```
DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE 1=1;
```

Comment: @slow-trout can you attempt deletion now

Comment: Unless there's a bug in the JDBC driver, this is equivalent to `DELETE FROM TABLENAME` (which reportedly did not work).

Comment: It's out of my reach. I am using a derby utilities release from somewhere in January so it might be a bug.